# Can pass a conditional statement as a function argument?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables

I have a main function and want to control 2 actions with it. Thereby I pass different variables to the function.

My question is **whether I can also pack the condition of an If query into a variable**.

For the one action I want to have `CurrentImageNumber <= 3` as an if argument and for the other action `CurrentImageNumber >= 2` in the if query.

The code would look something like this:

```
function imageChange() {
    CurrentImageNumber = parseInt(CurrentImageID.slice(-1)) // not a static value
    if (b) {
        // Some fancy Code where var a is used  
    }
    else {        
        // Some fancy Code where var c is used
    }
}

document.getElementById('button-1').onclick = function() {
    imageChange(a = 1, b = CurrentImageNumber <= 3, c = -3)    
}

document.getElementById('button-2').onclick = function() {
    imageChange(a = -1, b = CurrentImageNumber >= 2, c = 2)    
}
```

Comment: What would be the point? To save two lines?

Comment: In the given example - yes. In the actual code it saves me about 30 lines.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem--a more realistic example might be in order. Seems like there's at least an abstraction missing.

Comment: Okay, thanks fo the hint. I'm gonna update the example in a couple of minutes

Comment: I don't understand--just pass parameters. Don't try to use global variables as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do this, but what actually happens is, the condition is checked and the `predicate` returns a `boolean` value which is parsed into the function.

This would be done like so:

```
doStuff(CurrentImageNumber <= 4);

function doStuff(a) {
  if (a) {
  // Execute some fancy code
  }
}
```

But what actually happens during runtime is equivalent to this:
Lets say CurrentImageNumber == 0:

```
const predicateResult = CurrentImageNumber <= 4;
// Here predicateResult is of type boolean and is true
doStuff(predicateResult);

function doStuff(a) {
  if (a) {
  // Execute some fancy code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function needs a parameter variable to get the argument.

```
doStuff(CurrentImageNumber >= 2)
doStuff(CurrentImageNumber <= 4)

function doStuff(a) {
  if (a) {
    // execute some fancy code
  }
}
```